# Display custom FCM push notification in React Native iOS

Tags: react-native, firebase-notifications

I am working on a react native project which wants to receive the FCM push notification. And I am using the [react-native-fcm](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm) module. What I want to do is to show the notification manually.

In this module, there is a function

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native';
import FCM, {FCMEvent, RemoteNotificationResult, WillPresentNotificationResult, NotificationType} from 'react-native-fcm';

FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, async (notif) => {
  console.log(notif);
});
```

where the 'notif' should be the message that was received by the device. However, I cannot receive the  `console.log(notif);` is never called when the notification was sent to the device.

What I want to do is to use the following function to show the notification by handling the `notif` json manually.

```
FCM.presentLocalNotification({
        id: "UNIQ_ID_STRING",                               // (optional for instant notification)
        title: "My Notification Title",                     // as FCM payload
        body: "My Notification Message",                    // as FCM payload (required)
        sound: "default",                                   // as FCM payload
        priority: "high",                                   // as FCM payload
        click_action: "ACTION",                             // as FCM payload
        badge: 10,                                          // as FCM payload IOS only, set 0 to clear badges
        number: 10,                                         // Android only
        ticker: "My Notification Ticker",                   // Android only
        auto_cancel: true,                                  // Android only (default true)
        large_icon: "ic_launcher",                           // Android only
        icon: "ic_launcher",                                // as FCM payload, you can relace this with custom icon you put in mipmap
    });
```

I also realize that the message sent for FCM also would affect how the module to show the message. For more details, check [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).

I guess my FCM setup should be correct as I can receive the notification. My react-native app can receive the notification if I send the message with key `"notification"`. Like:

```
"notification":{
  "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "body":"great match!"
}
```

But the `console.log(notif);` in the previous function still haven't been called.

I also tried to send the notification with payload

```
"data" : {
  "title" : "Mario",
  "body" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
}
```

But the `console.log(notif);` is still not been called.

Does anyone know about the mechanism how react-native-fcm and firebase-cloud-messaging work?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to get FCM token, which should be registered with firebase. After successful registration, You will receive the remote notifications in "notif".

```
FCM.on(FCMEvent.RefreshToken, (token) => {
    console.log("registration token:" + token);
// fcm token may not be available on first load, catch it here
```

});